# discord.py bot: on_message detecting bot await send() messages

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there a way to detect when a user (not the bot itself) has sent a message? I understand that the on_message event allows comparisons to an expected command/ response (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) but for my project, there is no set user response. This makes it so the bot triggers everytime it detects it's own message. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
client = discord.Client()
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    #then write the code down here so if the person who send message is bot it wont count
```

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately the client.user returns a None for me. The message.author returns my user object perfectly fine but the client.user is not working

Comment: what I did instead was message.author != 'bot name'. I guess that is a solution although not the best

Comment: my code worked for me, try using commands bot.commands